trying to setup a ruby on rails project on my laptop to locally run so that i can perform the frontend changes and see them live
rails -v (6.0.3)
ruby -v (2.6.8)
pg -v (1.2.3)
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' succeeds before
bundling.
application is in staging and deployed on heroku but i was preferring to run it locally instead make changes to git repository and only push the changes once im ready with the frontend
I tried running the app locally but there is issue with sqlite tried to skip db setup as well since frontend is all im interested in but i couldnt skip it as well since there is uninitialized name error for friendly_id as it is missing active records

What is the error message when you run ‘gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'’

I think you might be underestimating the difficulty of the task. I'm not saying this to discourage you but to get a rails app running you're most likely going to need to not just get the database running but also any other dependencies. If you're going into this task by playing whack-a-mole with the errors instead of understanding what it is that you're actually doing you're going to have a very bad time. You can't just run the frontend of a monolithic rails app separate from the backend.

just run gem install sqlite3 -v 1.4.4 in your terminal before running bundle install, this will check the dependencies not only w.r.t rails but also with ruby environment.

I was able to run the application on local machine with the database running, Thank you the error was in the M2 chip architecture that was incompatible with sqlite3.
solution:
manually need to update the automake files config.guess and config.sub to support arm64-darwin platforms. (see https://sqlite.org/forum/info/73165e901d798571)
